# Linear vs. Audio Taper for RC Network

Tags: audio, circuit-analysis, potentiometer

I'm building a distortion pedal and I was wondering which tapers to use for which potentiometers in the tone control section. I normally design my own circuits, but I'm going by someone else's schematic this time. While I'm very familiar with simple RC filters and use them all the time, I don't quite know how this network works.

[image: schematic]

I'm guessing that the BASS pot should have an audio taper because it *seems* like it's effectively a normal, first-order RC high-pass filter, which would have a cutoff frequency of 1/(2πRC). I also think that maybe the TREB pot should be linear, because it seems like it's mixing signals between nodes A and B. I have no idea what taper MID should use.

What tapers should I use for each pot? How can I determine which tapers to use for similar networks in the future? What is each pot doing? I know I have a lot of questions, but I very much want to learn.

Comment: Why don't you download LTSpice and simulate it - you can alter the resistance values to suit the mechanical positions on the pot. I will add this - in my experience tone controls are linear and volume controls are log taper.

Comment: Tone control pots should be linear. You're modifying a turnover frequency, not an audio level.